# How to fork a non-GitHub repo on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, branch

Is there a best practice for this? I was thinking either to

- Create a repo, add original repo as upstream remote
- Create a "mirror" repo, then fork that
- Create a "mirror" repo, then create a "topic branch"
- Something else

related:
[help.github.com/send-pull-requests](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. Create new repo on GitHub
2. Clone the new repo

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:svnpenn/spoon-knife.git
   ```
3. Add source code from original repo

   ```
   cd Spoon-Knife
   git remote add upstream git://spoon.com/knife.git
   git fetch upstream
   git merge upstream/master
   ```
4. Push original source code to new repo

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```
5. At this point you can start committing your own source code!

source: [help.github.com/fork-a-repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo)

Comment: @anustart that link is already in the unedited answer. Did you have anything original to add?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub allows you to import an existing repository on Git, Subversion, Mercurial, and TFS.

See https://github.com/new/import