# Fork Git repo without fork button

Tags: git, github

I would like to fork this repo, git://git.rocketboards.org/linux-socfpga.git . But the problem is it is not hosted on Github, so there is no fork button. One idea came to me is to clone the repo to local, then upload to Github manually. But what if later I format the PC, will I lost the pull ability from upstream? Or a better question is what is the better solution for this?

Comment: Why would formatting the PC affect anything? You can always generate a new key and use that to push to GitHub.

Comment: Because I want to pull from time to time to keep my repo in line with to the upstream repo. If I format the PC, then git clone my Github repo to local again, how does it know who is its upstream? And even if we can edit some files to tell it, will it know from which point it should start pulling so it only pull whatever is missing since last pull?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fork a non-GitHub repo on GItHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268849/how-to-fork-a-non-github-repo-on-github)

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the repo and then uploading to Github (by creating an empty Github repository and setting that as a new remote) is the best answer. Forking is a concept on Github (not Git) that involves the other repository being cloned to a new repository on the server, so you're essentially doing exactly the same thing manually.

Additionally, your ability to change your repository or pull from upstream is not locked to that computer... If you later format your PC, simply re-clone your Github repository and add the linux-socfpga repository as a new remote.

Example: `git remote add upstream git://git.rocketboards.org/linux-socfpga.git`

This will re-add the upstream repository as a remote, which you can pull from via `git pull upstream master` (or whichever branch you're pulling from).